# HTML body not showing up in email when sent through MailApp.sendEmail()

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, html-email

I am trying to send an email through a google script, but although the email is received from the recipient, the body of the email shows up blank.
I am wondering if I am formatting the HTML document incorrectly? Or could it be that I am misusing the MailApp.sendEmail() API?

**Here is the code in the google script that sends the email**:

```js
function send_my_email(){
        var html_body = getEmailHtml();
        MailApp.sendEmail({
          to: "recipient@email.com",
          subject: "testing account balance update",
          htmlbody: html_body
          });
          }
function getEmailHtml() {
    var template_name = "Email_Template.html";
    var htmlTemplate = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile(template_name);
    var htmlBody = htmlTemplate.evaluate().getContent();
    return htmlBody;
  }
```

**and the HTML being sent from "Email_Template.html" is here**:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<div dir="ltr">
    <div class="gmail_quote">
        <br>
        <br>
        <div dir="ltr">Hello world,            <div>Below are the Account Balances for your team as of 8/31/2020 : </div>
            <div>
                <br>
            </div>
            <div>
                <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="685" style="border-collapse:collapse;width:514pt">

                    <colgroup>
                        <col width="290" style="width:218pt">
                            <col width="139" style="width:104pt">
                                <col width="256" style="width:192pt">
                    </colgroup>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr height="19" style="height:14.5pt">
                            <td colspan="3" height="19" width="685" style="height:14.5pt;width:514pt;font-weight:700;text-align:center;background:rgb(166,166,166);padding-top:1px;padding-right:1px;padding-left:1px;color:black;font-size:11pt;font-family:Calibri,sans-serif;vertical-align:bottom;border:none;white-space:nowrap">Account Balances as of 8/31/2020</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr height="19" style="height:14.5pt">
                            <td height="19" style="height:14.5pt;font-size:11pt;color:black;font-weight:700;font-family:Calibri,sans-serif;border-top:none;border-right:none;border-bottom:0.5pt solid rgb(142,169,219);border-left:none;background:rgb(217,225,242);padding-top:1px;padding-right:1px;padding-left:1px;vertical-align:bottom;white-space:nowrap">Name</td>
                            <td style="font-size:11pt;color:black;font-weight:700;font-family:Calibri,sans-serif;border-top:none;border-right:none;border-bottom:0.5pt solid rgb(142,169,219);border-left:none;background:rgb(217,225,242);padding-top:1px;padding-right:1px;padding-left:1px;vertical-align:bottom;white-space:nowrap">Account</td>
                            <td style="font-size:11pt;color:black;font-weight:700;font-family:Calibri,sans-serif;border-top:none;border-right:none;border-bottom:0.5pt solid rgb(142,169,219);border-left:none;background:rgb(217,225,242);padding-top:1px;padding-right:1px;padding-left:1px;vertical-align:bottom;white-space:nowrap">Sum of Account Balance as of 8/31/2020</td>
                        </tr>
                                                <tr height="19" style="height:14.5pt">
                            <td height="19" style="height:14.5pt;font-size:11pt;color:black;font-weight:700;font-family:Calibri,sans-serif;border:0.5pt solid windowtext;padding-top:1px;padding-right:1px;padding-left:1px;vertical-align:bottom;white-space:nowrap"> Kerby</td>
                            <td style="border-left:none;border-top:0.5pt solid windowtext;border-right:0.5pt solid windowtext;border-bottom:0.5pt solid windowtext;padding-top:1px;padding-right:1px;padding-left:1px;color:black;font-size:11pt;font-family:Calibri,sans-serif;vertical-align:bottom;white-space:nowrap">01-0111</td>
                            <td align="right" style="border-left:none;border-top:0.5pt solid windowtext;border-right:0.5pt solid windowtext;border-bottom:0.5pt solid windowtext;padding-top:1px;padding-right:1px;padding-left:1px;color:black;font-size:11pt;font-family:Calibri,sans-serif;vertical-align:bottom;white-space:nowrap">97.63</td>
                        </tr>
                                                <tr height="19" style="height:14.5pt">
                            <td height="19" style="height:14.5pt;font-size:11pt;color:black;font-weight:700;font-family:Calibri,sans-serif;border:0.5pt solid windowtext;padding-top:1px;padding-right:1px;padding-left:1px;vertical-align:bottom;white-space:nowrap"> Thomas the Tank Engine</td>
                            <td style="border-left:none;border-top:0.5pt solid windowtext;border-right:0.5pt solid windowtext;border-bottom:0.5pt solid windowtext;padding-top:1px;padding-right:1px;padding-left:1px;color:black;font-size:11pt;font-family:Calibri,sans-serif;vertical-align:bottom;white-space:nowrap">01-0444</td>
                            <td align="right" style="border-left:none;border-top:0.5pt solid windowtext;border-right:0.5pt solid windowtext;border-bottom:0.5pt solid windowtext;padding-top:1px;padding-right:1px;padding-left:1px;color:black;font-size:11pt;font-family:Calibri,sans-serif;vertical-align:bottom;white-space:nowrap">402.51</td>
                        </tr>
                                                <tr height="19" style="height:14.5pt">
                            <td height="19" style="height:14.5pt;font-size:11pt;color:black;font-weight:700;font-family:Calibri,sans-serif;border:0.5pt solid windowtext;padding-top:1px;padding-right:1px;padding-left:1px;vertical-align:bottom;white-space:nowrap"> Buzz Lightyear </td>
                            <td style="border-left:none;border-top:0.5pt solid windowtext;border-right:0.5pt solid windowtext;border-bottom:0.5pt solid windowtext;padding-top:1px;padding-right:1px;padding-left:1px;color:black;font-size:11pt;font-family:Calibri,sans-serif;vertical-align:bottom;white-space:nowrap">01-1234</td>
                            <td align="right" style="border-left:none;border-top:0.5pt solid windowtext;border-right:0.5pt solid windowtext;border-bottom:0.5pt solid windowtext;padding-top:1px;padding-right:1px;padding-left:1px;color:black;font-size:11pt;font-family:Calibri,sans-serif;vertical-align:bottom;white-space:nowrap">362.63</td>
                        </tr>
                                                <tr height="19" style="height:14.5pt">
                            <td height="19" style="height:14.5pt;font-size:11pt;color:black;font-weight:700;font-family:Calibri,sans-serif;border:0.5pt solid windowtext;padding-top:1px;padding-right:1px;padding-left:1px;vertical-align:bottom;white-space:nowrap"> Mini &amp; Mickey Mouse </td>
                            <td style="border-left:none;border-top:0.5pt solid windowtext;border-right:0.5pt solid windowtext;border-bottom:0.5pt solid windowtext;padding-top:1px;padding-right:1px;padding-left:1px;color:black;font-size:11pt;font-family:Calibri,sans-serif;vertical-align:bottom;white-space:nowrap">01-1234</td>
                            <td align="right" style="border-left:none;border-top:0.5pt solid windowtext;border-right:0.5pt solid windowtext;border-bottom:0.5pt solid windowtext;padding-top:1px;padding-right:1px;padding-left:1px;color:black;font-size:11pt;font-family:Calibri,sans-serif;vertical-align:bottom;white-space:nowrap">168.52</td>
                        </tr>
                        
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
            <div>
                <div dir="ltr" data-smartmail="gmail_signature">
                    <div dir="ltr">
                        <div>
                            <div dir="ltr">
                                <div>
                                    <div>
                                        <br>
                                    </div>
                                    <div>Please let us know if you have any questions!
                                        <br>Waldo</div>
                                    
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</html>
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Try making the name `var template_name = "Email_Template";`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about modifying as follows?

#### From:

```
htmlbody: html_body
```

#### To:

```
htmlBody: html_body
```

- In this case, `B` of `htmlBody` is the uppercase letter.

#### Reference:

- [sendEmail(message)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app#sendemailmessage)

Comment: It worked! wow, thats embarrassing! I didn't know that case mattered for those vars.

Comment: @Pswiss87 Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Although there are sometimes the case which can use both the uppercase and lowercase, in this case, the uppercase and lowercase of keys are important.